# why it cannot show anything in playground in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I try to use spriteKit to show something in playground in assistant editor. However, nothing showed. Below is the code. And if any one can show the results (a blue rectangle), please inform me. If not, please figure out where the problem is.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let view:SKView = SKView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 800))
let scene:SKScene = SKScene(size: CGSizeMake(1000, 800))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit

let blueBox: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(300, 300))
blueBox.position = CGPointMake(512, 384)
scene.addChild(blueBox)

view.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: How do you access TouchesBegan in your playground?

Answer (score 3):

You can see the current state of a view by clicking the QuickLook (eye) or circled-plus button in the sidebar. But to see your SpriteKit scene animate, you probably want a live view. For that, you need the XCPlayground framework.

```
import XCPlayground
XCPShowView("my SpriteKit view", view)
```

For details, read up on [Exploring and Evaluating Swift Code in a Playground](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/ExploringandEvaluatingSwiftCodeinaPlayground/ExploringandEvaluatingSwiftCodeinaPlayground.html) in Xcode Help or watch [WWDC 2014 session 408: Swift Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#408).

Comment: btw `XCPlayground` is OSX Only

Comment: Here I use UIKit, and it may not run in OSX, which could run XCPlayground. And I tried the eye button, but nothing happened.

Comment: SpriteKit is cross platform, so you can prototype in an OS X playground and then paste code into an iOS project. (With a few caveats, some of which you can deal with by using `SKColor` instead of `UIColor`.)

Comment: Note that even adding those lines do not result in the view appearing in the assistant editor. I've updated the question.

Comment: For now, it is `XCPShowView("my SpriteKit view", view: view)`

Comment: Now is `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = diagramView`, `XCPShowView` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As `XCPShowView` was deprecated in Xcode 7.1, use `PlaygroundPage` in `PlaygroundSupport` instead. The following is an example of using SpriteKit in Playground which is inspired from [this](http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/6/4/playing-with-spritekit-in-a-swift-playground).

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Create the SpriteKit View
let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

// Create the scene and add it to the view
let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
scene.backgroundColor = .white
view.presentScene(scene)

// Add a red box to the scene
let redBox = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
redBox.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
redBox.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -5, duration: 5)))
scene.addChild(redBox)

// Show in assistant editor
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```