# I get a error at "fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")"

Tags: swift, xcode8

I cant find a fix for the problem, Perhaps Im not implementing it right. I just get a blank white screen when i run it. I have tried different methods that I've seen on this site but none of them work. The error is highlighted on  "fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")". is there something obvious that Im missing?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene {


let gameArea: CGRect

override init(size: CGSize) {

    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
    gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)


    super.init(size: size)


 }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}




var Red = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red")
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var destX:CGFloat  = 0.0

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "stars")
    background.size = self.size
    background.zPosition = 0
    //background.setScale(1)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(background)




Red.setScale(0.25)
Red.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: -500)
self.addChild(Red)
Red.zPosition = 2




    if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable == true {

        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler:{
            data, error in

            let currentX = self.Red.position.x

           self.destX = currentX + CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 100)
        })





if Red.position.x > gameArea.maxX{
Red.position.x = gameArea.maxX
        }
if Red.position.x < gameArea.maxX{
Red.position.x = gameArea.maxX
        }



    }






    }

override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: destX, duration: 1)
    self.Red.run(action)
}



func firebullet (){

let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gul")
bullet.setScale(0.1)
bullet.position = Red.position
bullet.zPosition = 1
self.addChild(bullet)

let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.self.size.height, duration: 1)
let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let Bulletsequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
bullet.run(Bulletsequence)




}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?) {



firebullet ()




}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented error despite being implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966565/fatal-error-initcoder-has-not-been-implemented-error-despite-being-implement)

Comment: how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Instead of

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code in Playground with some additions and it's working fine. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700237/7113238) out.

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let gameArea: CGRect

    override init(size: CGSize) {

        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)


        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


// Create the SpriteKit View
let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

// Create the scene and add it to the view
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
scene.backgroundColor = .white
view.presentScene(scene)

// Add a red box to the scene
let redBox = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
redBox.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
redBox.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -5, duration: 5)))
scene.addChild(redBox)

// Show in assistant editor
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the code again, I added more so that it is not out of context.